# How to batch update a django M2M-relationship with intermediate model?

Tags: django, database, orm

I have two models and an intermediate one (simplified example):

```
class Book(model.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    owner=models.ManyToManyField(User, through="Ownership")

class Ownership(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User)
    book=models.ForeignKey(Book)
    read=models.BooleanField()
```

Now i already have a lot of `Book` objects and want to add all existing one to one user.

Currently i only see a manager API, which either constructs a `Ownership` models or adds an `Ownership` objects (possibly without saving?) to a `Book`. This would mean using a python loop over all `Book` objects and then constructing one `Ownership` object for each.

Is there a more efficient solution, like `Book.objects.update(owner=user, read=True)`, which is actually allowed in the django API?

Please do not mind minor syntax issues, the code is made up, as the actual code is a lot longer.

Comment: Maybe you mean `ManyToManyField` and `through` 
instead of `Many2Many` and `intermediate`?

Comment: Gotcha, is just wrote the code as pseudo code ;-). The actual code has the correct names of course. The question is how to update them in a batch (at best resulting in a single big SQL query at the backend).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a way without creating the Ownership objects, but you could commit them to the database with `bulk_create`:

```py
Ownership.objects.bulk_create(
    Ownership(read=True, user=user, book=book)
    for book in Book.objects.all())
```

You could avoid creating the Book objects by looping over the book ids:

```py
Ownership.objects.bulk_create(
    Ownership(read=True, user=user, book_id=book_id)
    for book_id in Book.objects.values_list('pk', flat=True))
```

There is a `batch_size` option to `bulk_create`, but it won't help split up the creation of Ownership objects so if many need to be created then lots of memory will be used. However, we can split them up ourselves to keep memory under control:

```py
count = Book.objects.count()
batch_size = 10**5
for i in range(0, count, batch_size):
    result = Ownership.objects.bulk_create(
        Ownership(read=True, user=user, book_id=book_id)
        for book_id in Book.objects.values_list('pk', flat=True)[i:min(i + batch_size, count)])
```

Comment: Thank you, bulk_create sounds good. I think there is no way to get around creating the Ownership one by one in some way, as they need to be added, not just updated anyway. I hope ``bulk_create`` is a bit more efficient than an python loop would be.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`bulk_create()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) to save multiple objects in one query:

```
# First create an unsaved Ownership object for each book
objs = [Ownership(user=user, book=book, read=True) for book in Book.objects.all()]
# Save all ownerships in one query
Ownership.objects.bulk_create(objs)
```